# Align ad layout at top

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to align an ad layout at the top of a Tab Layout and am not having much luck.  It seems to be stuck aligning at the bottom.  I've configured the Tab Layout so the tabs are at the bottom of the screen:

```
<TabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >        
       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp" 
     />

     <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="23dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
        android:layout_weight="0" 
     />    
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Update:

I fix it, I forgot I was setting the alignment in the code, like this:

```
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

Once I changed ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM to ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, it worked.

Comment: About halfway, at the end of the LinearLayout there's a `/>`, which shouldn't be there. Furthermore, I'd try treating the TabHost as a FrameLayout, since that's what it extends. Try playing around with the gravity of the different views. Finally, you could potentially put the TabHost into a ViewGroup and position the adLayout above that in that same ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of that extra closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your layout structure but what I understood is that you want to display ads at the top of the screen and for that I modify your code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/adLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_weight="0" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="0dp"
                 android:layout_below="@id/adLayout" android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
```